# Multiply Jquery and JqueryUI objects conflict? (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to put a script together that works with a Jquery object and a Jquery slider that also works with JqueryUI. I'm trying to figure out howto put it all together in a webpage (php) but trying to put just the slider in my webpage breaks both the functions and they don't work properly anymore.

Does anybody has an idea of what i am missing here and how the script fails to work properly?

***NOTE*** REMOVING V1.9 OR V1.3 DOESNT MATTER CAUSE THE SCRIPT STILL WORKS 50%, EITHER THE SLIDER DOESNT WORK OR THE AJAX CALLS IN SCRIPT.JS

*first load all scripts and styles.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="/shop/templates/Euphoria-Art/js/jquery.limitslider.js"></script>    
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/shop/templates/Euphoria-Art/js/script.js"></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

- SCRIPT.JS - There are 4 of these objects

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#formB'); //  form
  var submit = $('#submitB');  // submit button
  var alert = $('.pageB'); // div for show page
  // form submit event
   form.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

  $.ajax({
    url: '********/offertebeginC.php', // form action url
    type: 'post', // form submit method get/post
    dataType: 'json', // request type html/json/xml
    data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
    beforeSend: function() {
      alert.fadeOut();
    },
  success: function(result) {
      if(result.error){
          alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
          console.log(e)
      }else{
          alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
          form.trigger('reset');   
      }
  }

   });
  });
    });
  ```

Comment: Side note, including two copies of jQuery is never a solution.

Comment: You seem to have multiple jQuery libraries loading (1.9.1 and 1.3.0).

Comment: Ok i removed the jquery 1.3 but now the slider only works when u press between the DOTS and not when u try to slide him and that's what he needs to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must include multiple versions of jQuery, for instance using a plugin which depends on an earlier version, you'll want to use `$.noConflict()`.

Take a look at the [**docs here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), and a bit of a [**tutorial here**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: Thanks will take a look @ that.